# How to add disk in azure with ansible

Tags: azure, azure-storage, ansible

We created the instances on azure using this module (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/azure_module.html). However it does not show how to add extra VHD Disk. is there a way to add disks in azure with ansible?

Comment: [azure_rm_manageddisk](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/azure_rm_manageddisk_module.html)'s managed_by option can add/remove this disk to an existing VM

Answer (score 1):

```
   vars:

        vm2:
            - name: azu-ve109456
              network_interface:
                  name: azu-eu-west-subnet-a-ni-ve108456
              vm_size: Standard_DS1_v2
              username: ubuntu

  - name: Create VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: NAME
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      vm_size: "{{ item.vm_size }}"
      admin_username: "{{ item.username }}"
      ssh_password_enabled: false
      ssh_public_keys:
        - path: "/home/{{ item.username }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
          key_data: "ssh-rsa AAAABxxxxxxgxYN"
      network_interfaces: "{{ item.network_interface.name }}"
      image:
          offer: UbuntuServer
          publisher: Canonical
          sku: 16.04-LTS
          version: latest
      managed_disk_type: Premium_LRS
      data_disks:
          - lun: 0
            disk_size_gb: 64
            managed_disk_type: Premium_LRS
          - lun: 1
            disk_size_gb: 128
            managed_disk_type: Premium_LRS
          - lun: 2
            disk_size_gb: 128
            managed_disk_type: Premium_LRS

      with_items: "{{ vm2 }}"
```